# Unexpected result of Nginx

Tags: nginx, server, certbot

I've a server with 2 services on it. Software are Ubuntu20.04 OS, Nginx and certbot.
So, then I check `nginx` status:

```
~$ sudo systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-12-13 10:48:55 CET; 35min ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
....
des. 13 10:48:55 u nginx[248435]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
des. 13 10:48:55 u nginx[248435]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
des. 13 10:48:55 u systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
des. 13 10:48:55 u systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
des. 13 10:48:55 u systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

and checking of configuration:

```
~$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

But at the same time both services are up and working as they should. If I ask about nginxs' processes, i've next

```
~$ sudo ps -ax | grep nginx
 245336 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process
 245337 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process
 245338 ?        S      0:00 nginx: worker process
 250704 pts/7    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

and check one of them (it doesn't matter which one)

```
~$ sudo systemctl status 245336
● snap.certbot.certbot.***********.scope
     Loaded: loaded (/run/systemd/transient/snap.certbot.certbot.***********.scope; transien>
  Transient: yes
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-12-13 09:39:30 CET; 1h 35min ago
```

I can't imagine what happens and why it works in this way. Before this problem, I updated `certbot` and deleted a few certifates (they were expired and unused).

Who can explain me how it's work? And why are the services up?

Comment: Another process has taken control of port 80. This article will help you figure what:  https://www.tecmint.com/find-out-which-process-listening-on-a-particular-port/